# Add columns to a dataset without any columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to load a dataset into a dataframe and then add columns to the dataset. Right now when I add columns, it removes the first line of data.

To visualize for happens;

Let's assume the following data from a csv is loaded to the dataframe

21,5,14

456,47,1

47,89,66

```
# Assume that the user uploaded a CSV file
df = pd.read_csv(
            io.StringIO('csv_file_data', index_col=False, low_memory=False)
```

It will look like this

```
   21  5  14
0  456 47 1
1  47  89 66
```

So basically the first line of data is now shown as the columns, if your visualize the dataframe.

When, I try to add columns
Where, file_structure, is a list with the columns

```
df.columns = file_structure
```

Does now look like this;

```
   x   y  z
0  456 47 1
1  47  89 66
```

Comment: file_structure is a list, ['x', 'y', 'z']

Comment: use header=None and then run your code, it should work

Comment: Adding 'header=None' as parameter did the job! Thanks, iamklaus.. You want to make it as an answer?

Comment: @JohnDign How? then your question is not clear to me, you want to assign x, y, x as the columns and make the orginal columns a row, `header = None` isn't enough, also have you check mine yet?

Comment: header = None, put in columns that is 0, 1, 2....n, so this means that the first line of data is not set as columns and will not be overwritten when using the df.columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    df = pd.read_csv(
            io.StringIO(decoded.decode('utf-8')), index_col=False, low_memory=False, header=None, names=file_structure
)
```

names lets you set column names
header sets an index to use as colum names

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv

Comment: Isn't this just like mine?

Comment: Almost, it included the manual setting of header=None.
Which was was op needed.
Your edit uses the first line as index and then drops it. So the first row will be missing.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `names` parameter:

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('csv_file_date'), index_col=False, low_memory=False, names=file_structure)
```

Or if you don't want it when you read it do:

```
df = df.T.reset_index().T.reset_index(drop=True)
df.columns = file_structure
```

Comment: The thing is, I have to read in the data first, before adding.. Because the file includes a version at position 0,0 which determines which columns belong to the given dataset

Comment: @JohnDign Check the bottom part of my answer, and don't forget to accept and up-vote if it works.